# how to resolve clarity-icons.min.js version conflict in angular app

Tags: angular, angular-cli, vmware-clarity

I am running a demo from https://github.com/angular-in-action/portfolio to study angular .The Angular CLI version  of the demo is so old(it uses version 1.3.2,but the latest version is 7.3.9) that so many dependencies have been out of date,so I update the dependency by

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
```

But when I run the demo,it doesn't work.

From the log ,I can see that it was clarity-icons.min.js ,it has been move to the @clr/icons ,but I can not find where the code invokes the clarity-icons.min.js package,any idea?

here is package file :

```
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.15",
    "@clr/angular": "^1.1.3",
    "@clr/icons": "^1.1.3",
    "@clr/ui": "^1.1.3",
    "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "^1.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "mutationobserver-shim": "^0.3.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "webpack": "^4.31.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "7.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.15",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.12",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "~12.0.2",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.16.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

here is log file :

```
/snap/bin/node /snap/node/2023/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
    run start --scripts-prepend-node-path=auto

    > portfolio@0.0.0 start /home/maple/typescript/portfolio
    > ng serve

    ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **  92% additional asset
    processing scripts-webpack-plugin✖ ｢wdm｣: Error: ENOENT: no such
    file or directory, open
    '/home/maple/typescript/portfolio/node_modules/clarity-icons/clarity-icons.min.js'
        at Object.openSync (fs.js:438:3)
        at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
        at Storage.provideSync (/home/maple/typescript/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:98:13)
        at CachedInputFileSystem.readFileSync (/home/maple/typescript/portfolio/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:259:32)
        at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable.obs [as _subscribe] (/home/maple/typescript/portfolio/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/webpack-input-host.js:35:51)
        at Observable._trySubscribe (/home/maple/typescript/portfolio/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:44:25)
        at Observable.subscribe (/home/maple/typescript/portfolio/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:30:22)
        at SyncDelegateHost._doSyncCall (/home/maple/typescript/portfolio/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/virtual-fs/host/sync.js:22:20)
        at SyncDelegateHost.read (/home/maple/typescript/portfolio/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/virtual-fs/host/sync.js:49:21)
        at WebpackCompilerHost.readFileBuffer (/home/maple/typescript/portfolio/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/compiler_host.js:125:44)
        at VirtualFileSystemDecorator.readFile (/home/maple/typescript/portfolio/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/virtual_file_system_decorator.js:39:54)
        at Promise (/home/maple/typescript/portfolio/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/scripts-webpack-plugin.js:69:49)
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at scripts.map.fullPath (/home/maple/typescript/portfolio/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/scripts-webpack-plugin.js:68:24)
        at Array.map (<anonymous>)
        at hook (/home/maple/typescript/portfolio/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/scripts-webpack-plugin.js:67:43)
    ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /
```

Comment: As the author of that demo, I know it is out of date as far as NPM packages (But Angular CLI went from 1.x to 6.x in a single release, so its not that far out of date in reality). The reason I haven't updated is that from an educational standpoint, everything should still work in a newer version. I also don't want the content in the book to shift without publishing an update.

Comment: great demos,I have run several of them,they are enough for common use.I will try to keep the environment consistent as yours.I try to update the dependencies so  i can test my understanding of angular.A book with good demos is much more interesting than the doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update your angular application, you should probably follow the [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/).

With `ncu -u` command, I think you are missing some essential steps like switching to HttpClientModule.

If you are using the guide, you will find all the necessary steps to correctly update you application.

I checked on the repo and it seems the version used is the 5.0.0-beta.6, so I guess you have to follow **Angular Update Guide | 5.0 -> 7.0 for Basic Apps**